# Unable to connect to Management Studio an "error occured while connecting to the SQL Server"

Tags: sql-server, connect, sql-server-2016-express

I'm familiar with basic SQL through work but I'm trying to improve. All I want to do is create my own local database on my laptop to play around with and follow online tutorials.

I've been trying all night to login to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016 but I just cannot connect. I have SQL Server 2016 Express installed and I am selecting "Database Engine", "local" / ".", Windows Authentication. I get the very generic

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while connecting to the SQL Server

error message.

I've checked on Windows services, as many guides advise, and I can see SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) is running with an automatic start.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what. Can anyone help? I'm really stuck.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that your Express edition is installed in a named instance and you aren't specifying it when connection to the database server.  You can see if it has a named instance by looking for the service in Services (under Administrative Tools).  The service will be called `SQL Server (INSTANCE NAME)`.

Comment: Did you try searching (via Google or here) on the exact error message you're getting? (Apparently not, as there are dozens of existing posts here that have been answered related to that message.) Please do some basic research first before posting a new question here. A simple search is the most basic research you can do.

Comment: Ken, did you read where I mentioned that I'd "trying all night" to login? Do you really think a simple google search did not occur to me?

Comment: @MartinParkin - Thank you so much, I have solved it now. It was down to the specific instance not being asked for. Many guides advised just using a dot or "local", this didn't work for me. I used "_<MY PC NAME>_\SQLEXPRESS" successfully.

Comment: @jm0987 Good stuff.  I'll add an answer to this question for future Google searchers.  If you could accept it that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that your Express edition is installed in a named instance and you aren't specifying it when connection to the database server.

You can see if it has a named instance by looking for the service in Services (under Administrative Tools).

The service will be called `SQL Server (INSTANCE NAME)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, for anyone finding this via google you can find the service name: run->services.msc->find SQL Server